# COOKIE php programming

Tags: php

I am absolutely new to server programming, but the task was to do the following:
After sending the feedback form using the post method, it redirects to the thank you page, and having left it either by rebooting or by history, I should not get to it again in this session.
In fact, if I am on the thank you page and I refresh the page, it takes me to the main page, if I go back in history (back in the browser), then in any case I should not get into it again.
Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      var_dump($_COOKIE);
      die();
  }

  setCookie("submit_cookie", $visited, time() + 86400, "/order-contacts");

  if (isset($_COOKIE["submit_cookie"])) {
     setCookie("submit_cookie", $visited, time() - 86400, "/order-contacts");
     die();
  }
```

Нere: /order-contacts - thank you page I should get to

I’ll explain how I understand the implementation:
First, I check if I execute the post request by submit, then I analyze the cookie and die afterwards. Next, I’ll write down the cookie and then check if the cookies have completed and I got to the thank you page, then I cancel the cookie action and accordingly I can’t re-enter this page
Do not judge strictly, I am just studying, I wanted to find out if I think correctly in terms of building logic, and I wanted to find out where the error is because the cookie is not written

Comment: _“because the cookie is not written”_ - and how exactly did you determine that? You are aware that you made it valid only underneath the path `/order-contacts` to begin with, and what that actually means?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the cookie will be recorded after the request is completed, that is, I should write to the cookies before the POST request is executed, and not after, but determined through the console, I sent the data from the form and redirected me to the thank you page, then through the developer’s console and searched traces marker =

Comment: If you set a cookie before the form was even submitted the first time, how do you expect to get your “thank you” page to get shown _at all_ then?

Comment: I work with modx and made the form a formit component and accordingly, by clicking on submit, I put a redirect to the thank you page,  the form is sent, redirecting takes place.

Comment: it’s just that if I understood correctly, the cookies will be written after the request is completed, that is, if I install at the time before the submission, and when the submission is completed, a request will be made and I will receive cookies of the thank you page

Comment: I can not currently tell if you are just using weird phrasing to describe these things, or if you are actually off in your understanding. Let’s get back to what I mentioned in the first comment already, the path issue. Are you aware what it _means_ when you set a cookie with that path parameter? It is not clear what you are sending from where to where here (spekaing in terms of under which actual URLs this happens), so it is currently impossible to tell whether that might be your problem already, or something else.

Comment: Let's go back: the path in the parameter: the path to the directory from which cookies will be available. If you set it simply / we get that cookies will be available on all pages, if you set something like / exapmle / then in the directory / exapmle / and in all subcategories like / example / next

Comment: As I understand it

Comment: Yes. So how does that fit into what you are currently doing, what data are you sending from where (URL) to where? And have you tried not specifying a path, so that the cookie would be valid through the whole site? (Even if you want to restrict it more later on, this could at least tell you whether your problem is due to the path, or something else.)

Comment: That is, if I understood correctly, I must indicate there the path that I will get from after completing the request to the thank you page.

Comment: Once again I apologize for asking such questions, distracting you, there’s simply no one to ask, which is not clear, the forum remains

Comment: If you specify a path, then you specify which URLs the cookie will be send to the server for in the first place. You still haven’t explained what you are sending from what URL to where. Therefor my suggestion, try without specifying a path first, so that the cookie is valid for the whole site.

Comment: Good afternoon! Please tell me if (isset ($ _ POST ['submit'])) will perform the actions before clicking submit? So, I have to write cookies before clicking submit and as a result, clicking on submit will execute a request and I will receive cookies of thanks page

Comment: No, of course the parameter resulting from clicking the submit button and submitting the form, will not be set before that has happened.